# Modal Logic backward looking modality

Tags: logic, modal-logic

For an exercise in Modal Logic I have to solve the next problem, can someone please help?

Use generated submodels to show that the backward looking modality (that is, P of the basic temporal language) cannot be defined in terms of the forward looking operator $\diamond $.

I think I have to use that a formula $\phi$ can be true in the generated submodel but not in the original model. Probably I have to assume that it is possible to define the backward looking modality in terms of $\diamond$ and then search for a contradiction.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The exercise is from *Modal logic* by *Patrick Blackburn et al.* The approach is the same as in the **Example 2.4**, i.e. you assume, that the backward looking modality is definable in the basic modal language (that is using $\diamond$). Then, according to the **Proposition 2.6**, some formula $\varphi$, which might include the new modality, is true in some state of a model if and only if it is true in the same state of the generated submodel. Let use the model and the generated submodel from the **p. 55** and the state $\bf0$. We can "look backwards" in the model (i.e. $\bf{-1}R\bf0$), but we cannot do so in the generated submodel (since there is no state $s$, such that $sR\bf{0}$), which is the contradiction.

Comment: Tanks! This was really helpful.